# How can I configure call depth in PowerShell?

Tags: exception, powershell, recursion

I was just trying things in PowerShell and got an error about *call depth* being set to 1000 in some test recursive function. I looked on the Internet for some information and found that this is due to error handling in PowerShell (if I got it right):

> The recursion depth limit is fixed in version 1. Deep recursion was causing problems in 64-bit mode because of the way exceptions were being processed. It was causing cascading out-of-memory errors. The net result was that we hard-limited the recursion depth on all platforms to help ensure that scripts would be portable to all platforms. 
>   - Bruce Payette, co-designer of PowerShell

I found it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/12/15/working-around-a-powershell-call-depth-disaster-with-trampolines.aspx).

Also I found this exception page on MSDN that states this limit is configurable (but I didn't find anything about how to do this) - see remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptcalldepthexception(v=vs.85).aspx).

**How can this limit be set?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In **PowerShell V1** the maximum call depth is 100:

Using [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector), we can see in this snippet from the `System.Management.ExecutionContext` class code,

```
internal int IncrementScopeDepth()
{
    using (IDisposable disposable = tracer.TraceMethod("{0}", new object[] { this.scopeDepth }))
    {
        if (this.CurrentPipelineStopping)
        {
            throw new PipelineStoppedException();
        }
        this.scopeDepth++;
        if (this.scopeDepth > 100)
        {
            ScriptCallDepthException exceptionRecord = new
            ScriptCallDepthException(this.scopeDepth, 100);
            tracer.TraceException(exceptionRecord);
            throw exceptionRecord;
        }
        return this.scopeDepth;
    }
}
```

that it is not possible to modify the ***hardcoded 100***.

- In **PowerShell V2** the maximum call depth is 1000

Again when looking at the code, there doesn't seem to be a way around the default maximum call depth.

- In **PowerShell V3 (CTP)** there doesn't seem to be a maximum call depth (unless you run out of resources of course). This behaviour has been [described as a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/746032/v3-rc-hangs-on-deep-recursive-calls-with-not-predictable-recursion-depth) on connect, so it might change in the final version.

Comment: Nice work there. So this would mean there is a mistake in the docentation, right? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: @jumbo Yes, it's a documentation bug, unless I got it wrong. :-) I updated the information with regards to V3 with a reference to a bug filed on connect by Roman Kuzmin.