# Recursive svn upgrade in local filesystem (Win32)

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, recursion, cmd

There is a need to recursively run svn upgrade in certain directory in filesystem, ignoring non-svn subdirectories:

```
C:\a>svn upgrade
C:\a\b>svn upgrade
<skip non-svn dir>
C:\a\b\c>svn upgrade
...
```

This means we need to run svn upgrade command in every folder that has `.svn` inside it. How this can be done in win32? Found `for d in find . -name .svn -type d; do svn upgrade $d/..; done` routine for posix OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn upgrade` needs to be run at the top level of each working copy - you don't want to recurse into a WC 3 levels deep and then run it there, as you'll hose the WC. Reason: SVN pre-1.7 had a `.svn` directory in each directory of the working copy, while 1.7+ uses a single `.svn` in the root of the WC.

So, your recursion has to guarantee that you'll touch the top levels first - then as you go deeper if you find a `.svn` directory, you know it's a separate WC and not a child of another.

Batch is dead, use PowerShell. Put this in a `.ps1` file (or the PowerShell ISE) and run it:

```
function upgrade-svndirs {
param (
    [string]$PathToUpgrade
    )
    $Dirs = get-childitem $PathToUpgrade|where-object{$_.PSIsContainer};
    foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
        $DirName = $dir.FullName;
        $isWC = Get-ChildItem $DirName -Filter ".svn" -Force;
        if ($isWC) {
            svn upgrade "$DirName";
        }
        upgrade-svndirs -PathToUpgrade $DirName;
    }

}

upgrade-svndirs C:\a;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've meant when was asking this question, thanks. Any chance to import this function to PowerShell (at least during some session)? So I could use it few times with different parameters without editing script file itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can define it in your `$Profile` or just save it as a `.ps1` file (minus the last line of my code here) and execute it that way as needed (`path_to_ps1file path_to_upgrade`)

Comment: When I'm executing the whole script (with upgrade-svndirs target_dir; last line) it still tries to execute it in directory where script lies, not target one. When I remove last line and do "upgrade-svndirs.ps1 target-dir" it does nothing at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: When I run it eventually, it throws exception at some point: The script failed due to call depth overflow.  The call depth reached 1001 and the maximum is 1000. 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1001:Int32) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CallDepthOverflow

Comment: You didn't specify that your directory tree is so deep. PowerShell v2 has a [recursion depth limit of 1000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755699/how-can-i-configure-call-depth-in-powershell), while v3 is limited by your computer's resources. Can you start deeper in the tree?